# Segmentation Fault 11 when trying to create new linked list from sorted list

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

Just to explain what is going on, I am inputting a sorted linked list into a method. In this linked list are nodes that contain strings. The nodes contain the string, and 2 counters that will be mentioned later. These strings are alphanumerical and can repeat. In the end, I want to output a linked list in which each node contains a unique word (all lowercased), a counter for number of occurrences, and a counter for different variances of the word (variances are caused by different capitalizations of certain characters). I believe it works logically; however, I get a segmentation fault.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef int bool;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


struct Node{
  char value[100];
  int numOccur;
  int numVariance;
  struct Node *next;
};




struct Node * getFinalNodes(struct Node *head){
    struct Node * curr;
    struct Node * finalNode;
    struct Node * ptr;
    struct Node * finalCurr;
    struct Node * prev;
    int m = 0;
    int z = 0;
    char lowercase1[100];
    char lowercase2[100];

    curr = head;                                        //curr = head of sorted node
    finalNode = head;
    ptr = finalNode;
    finalCurr = finalNode;

    for(m = 0; curr->value[m] != '\0'; m++){
        finalNode->value[m] = tolower(curr->value[m]);          //gets first word all lower-cased
    }

    ptr->numOccur=1;                                     //occurance is 1
    ptr->numVariance=1;                                  //variance is 1
    while(curr != NULL && curr->next != NULL){
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        if((strcmp(prev->value, curr->value) != 0) && (strlen(prev->value) == strlen(curr->value))){            //example: Ab vs. AB
            for(z=0; curr->value[z] != '\0'; z++){                                                               //turn prev and curr into lowercase
                lowercase1[z] = tolower(prev->value[z]);                                                        //ex. Ab->ab and AB->ab
                lowercase2[z] = tolower(curr->value[z]);
            }
            if(strcmp(lowercase1,lowercase2) == 0){                                                              //if values are same, that means they are the same words, just different capitalizations
                ptr->numOccur++;
                ptr->numVariance++;
            }
            else{                                                                                               //if values are different, then they are completely different strings and put curr.value into a new finalNode
                strcpy(finalNode->value,lowercase2);
                ptr->next = finalNode;
                ptr = ptr->next;
                ptr->numOccur = 1;
                ptr->numVariance =1;
            }
        }
        else if((strcmp(prev->value, curr->value) != 0) && (strlen(curr->value) != strlen(prev->value))){                                                                     //created arrays for prev and curr
            for(z=0; curr->value[z] != '\0'; z++){                                                               //turn prev and curr into lowercase                                                      //ex. Ab->ab and AB->ab
                lowercase2[z] = tolower(curr->value[z]);
            }
            strcpy(finalNode->value,lowercase2);
            ptr->next = finalNode;
            ptr = ptr->next;
            ptr->numOccur = 1;
            ptr->numVariance =1;
       }
       else if(strcmp(prev->value, curr->value) == 0){
            ptr->numOccur++;
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: Put the code in a debugger.  It will tell you which line the seg-fault is on.  Use the debugger to inspect your variables, and you'll learn why.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop

```
while(curr != NULL){
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
    if((strcmp(prev->value, curr->value) != 0) && (strlen(prev->value) == strlen(curr->value))){
```

`curr` is `NULL` at the end after `curr = curr->next;`.

Then `strcmp(prev->value, curr->value)` dereferences a null pointer.

You could change the loop condition to

```
while(curr != NULL && curr->next != NULL)
```

Comment: I changed that and it got rid of the segmentation fault! However, it seems that nothing gets outputted from the method...

Comment: You have no `return` in that function, didn't the compiler complain about that?

Comment: @DanielFischer The compiler doesn't necessarily complain about a non-void function not returning in all code paths. It's *probably* undefined behavior, but in practice what *might* happen is that a value in the stack will be assumed by the caller to be the returned value.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis It's undefined behaviour if and only if the non-existent return value is used. But a good compiler will warn about "control reaches end of non-void function" or similar when it detects that. At least if you ask it to warn about dubious constructs.

Comment: @DanielFischer True, this is undefined only if it's ever used. And yes, you're correct that with the right flags, the compiler will warn you. But I sort of remember GCC not warning me about this by default. I may be remembering things wrong, though.

Comment: GCC warns about missing returns under `-Wall`.  If you're using GCC and aren't using `-Wall`, you had better be a very good programmer indeed.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I don't know, my alias for gcc contains `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, so I get warned if I forget a return in a path the compiler can find. By default, iirc, gcc is rather lenient. But on the other hand, it warns about some not particularly dubious things by default.